# Law of Cosines vs. Law of Sines Two different Answers

Tags: trigonometry

A question on my trigonometric test a student solved using both law of sines and law of cosines and got similar but different results (I've double checked the calculations and cannot think of a reason they would be different). Vector one $~12~$ lb pulls on a sled at an angle of $~15^{\circ}~$  "above" the $~x$-axis, vector two $~18~$ lbs pulls on the the sled at an angle of $~10^{\circ}~$ "below" the $~x$-axis. What is the magnitude of the resultant force?

The law of cosines calculation where $x$ is the magnitude of the diagonal of the parallelogram yields $x^2 = 12^2+18^2-2(12)(18) \cos(155)$

$x = 29.3176$ lb

If using the law of sines:

$\frac{\sin(155)}{x} = \frac{\sin(10)}{12}$

$x = 29.2051$ lb

If the $~15^{\circ}~$ angle is used instead of the $~10^{\circ}~$ the answer is a little higher than law of cosines answer. Breaking the vectors up into $~x~$ and $~y~$ components, adding them and finding the magnitude yields the same answer as law of cosines.

Comment: The diagonal is not the $x$-axis!  Indeed the other two angles of the relevant triangle are obscure.  I get $15.039^{\circ}$ and $9.961^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

It was a good idea to do the problem a third way -- it gives more credence to the law of cosines answer than to the law of sines answer. Additionally, you seem to be somewhat uncomfortable with the law of sines method -- you mention that you consider using $25$ degrees instead of $10$ degrees, so you are at least somewhat unsure what that angle should be.

You're thus very close to the root of the issue: the angle between the parallelogram's diagonal and the bottom vector is unknown. It's not $10$ degrees (that's the angle between the x-axis and the bottom vector), and it's not $25$ degrees (that's the angle between the top vector and the bottom vector). We can't apply the law of sines because we don't have two known angles.

Comment: Thank you, the 25 was a typo, have edited it. On the drive home I was thinking that I can’t force the diagonal to be where I want it (since the problem gives 4 numbers that have to agree).  Even in the question I write the diagonal is not the x-axis, but was trying to word the question more simple here.